# Machine Learning on Time Series Data - Cross Validation

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, python

I am new to Machine Learning in Time Series and want to build a machine learning model to forecast monthly returns. I have over 200 features to build my model, here's the shape of my data: [image]

First, I've tried `cross_val_score` with `Time_Series_Split()`:

```py
index_output = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits = 10)
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 400, random_state = 1234)
scores = cross_val_score(rf, X_train, y_train, cv=index_output)
```

Then I tried `RandomizedSearchCV()`:

```py
index_output = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits = 10)
rf = RandomForestRegressor()
model = RandomizedSearchCV(
    estimator = rf,
    param_distributions = random_grid,
    n_iter = 10,
    n_jobs = -1,
    cv = index_output,
    verbose=5,
    random_state = 42,
    return_train_score = True)
model.fit(X_train.drop('Date', axis=1),y_train)
model.cv_results_
```

Both of my approaches did not work, but I haven't seen a simple example of `Time_series_Split()` yet. How do I need to change my approaches to build my model using Time Series Split? Especially the randomized search?

Error in my first approach is:

> C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_validation.py:536: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details:
> TypeError: invalid type promotion
> FitFailedWarning)

Comment: your splitting strategy is correct

Comment: You might find this paper useful. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.11744.pdf

Comment: Thaks for the paper. I just don't know how to implement it in python. I've added the error now